# Chrome extension: Cross origin request

Tags: javascript, browser-extensions, crossdomain

Can chrome extensions make cross-origin requests by injecting a javascript into the main page? If so, isn't it a security vulnerability?

[Google Chrome Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)

[Cross Origin Requests](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421933/cross-origin-xmlhttprequest-in-chrome-extensions has some relevant information

Answer (score 3):

Actually, they don't even have to inject JavaScript into the main page. Extensions can require permissions to make Cross-Origin requests to certain websites, see https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr. They can even use the `<all_urls>` permission to get Cross-Origin access for all websites. This is not a security vulnerability, as you have to manually install an extension and grant the permissions on installation, making you responsible for anything that happens.